# Why Order Failed to Avatax in magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have started getting this notification 'The AvaTax Queue has 492 document(s) that failed during processing and were not successfully sent to AvaTax'.

Please help m,e to fix this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

- This can happen from time to time if a problem order gets stuck in your sync queue, thus stopping your CronJob.
- To resolve this, go into the backend manually, and delete the problem orders, which should free up the queue to process pending Cron jobs:

- Make a backup of your database
- Delete items from the database table `op_avatax_queue`.
- Make sure you delete only those Pending transactions that are worth deleting.